# How to $watch all but one or two properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a state property on my models by using $watch to mark a model dirty when any of the properties change:

```
        $scope.$watch(
            function (scope) {
                return scope.item;
            },
            function (newItem, oldItem) {
                if (newItem !== oldItem) {
                    newItem.setStateDirty();
                }
            });
```

The (somewhat obvious) problem is that any changes to the state property also trigger the watch.

Without explicitly comparing all properties to determine if only the state property has changed, is it possible to somehow ignore changes to the state property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by approaching the problem from a different direction.  Instead of using simple JavaScript objects for my models, I am now defining model properties using `object.defineProperty()`.  This allows me to explicitly set the dirty flag in the setter of specific properties.

**For example:**

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "title",
    {
        set: function (value) {
                _title = value;
                this.dirty = true;
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `$watch` function you can return a new object which contains all the properties of your `item` except the properties which you do not want to $watch.

```
$scope.$watch(
    function (scope) {
        // return a new object in which the dirty property is always undefined
        // and therefore will not trigger the watch
        return angular.extend({}, scope.item, {dirty: undefined});
    },
    function (newItem, oldItem) {
        if (newItem !== oldItem) {
            newItem.setStateDirty();
        }
    });
```

Comment: interesting suggestion but I wonder if, for performance reasons, it might be unwise to do that in the $watch listener.